# img will not render in Safari

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, safari, safari-web-inspector

I am working on a legacy application which works in ie but not in Safari.
The image in the code will not render in Safari.

```
     <section class="feature pointer clickableSection tooltipContainer" id="SearchSection" 
                    data-scd-nextScreen="@Url.Action("FullSearch", "Company")"data-placement="bottom"
                    data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Click here to SEARCH Addresses">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/phonebook.png")" alt="Click here to SEARCH Addresses" />
            <h3><span style="text-decoration: underline">Search Addresses</span><span id="searchHeading"></span></h3>
            <div class="loadMessage"></div>       
        </section>
```

I have got the Safari Web Inspector up and running, but I cannot see where I can find out where the problem is. I am new to using this tool.

Comment: Your server code is irrelevant to the question. Please show your actual output.

Comment: What you see from this section is the header text in the <h3> element, ie Search Addresses, but the <img> element above it does not render in Safari - it does in ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem is.
In my CSS which I did not publish, it has;

```
section.feature img {
    color: #999;
    /*content: attr(alt);*/
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 140px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I have commented out the line that is not compatable with Safari, ie content: attr(alt);